# Efficiency for many-to-one relationship

Tags: python, django

Currently, we are building a commercial API as service.

We have a following requirement.

1. User will login via email
2. Each user has a unique API key
3. Every consumption of API, there will be a log for audit purpose.

We plan to use the following custom user model.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin

    def get_fields(self):
        return [(field.name, field.value_to_string(self)) for field in User._meta.fields]

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    api_key = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.api_key)

class ApiLog(models.Model):
    api_consumed = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    date_consumed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Is the above a good data models for Django?**

Our worry is, a user will produce hundred thousand row of new `ApiLog` rows. We need not to access those data very frequent, unless when comes to audit period.

However, we will construct existing `User` object very often. I was wondering, will a large number of row of `ApiLog` per `User`, will it slow down construction of existing.

As, `User` object contains `user.apilog_set`, which may contains few hundred thousand line of rows.

Comment: This seems like a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The number of rows in one table will have minimal (reverse logarithmic) impact on selects in table and none on selects in an table a foreign key points to (or from). Of cause this expects indexes to be in use.